# How to avoid the repetation of date and voucher number?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

My database

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1v3M.png)

This my database "journal"

I have got the result:
[Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C72Pp.png)

My problem is I have displayed the voucher number and date into only one time, it is repeated on my result.
How to display as one.

My controller code:

```
        public function Journal_Print(){
        $data['startdate'] =$this->input->post('SDate');
            $data['enddate'] = $this->input->post('EDate');
            $PName  = $this->input->post('TName');

                $startdate = $this->input->post('SDate');
            $enddate = $this->input->post('EDate');
            $date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
            $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
            $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
            $newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
            $data['startdate'] = $startdate;
            $data['enddate'] = $enddate;




    $this->db->where('Date >=',  $newDate);
          $this->db->where('Date <=',  $newDate2);



          $query = $this->db->get('journal');    
            $data['PName']=$query->result_array();
        //  print_r($data);

            $this->load->view('BookKeeping/Journal_Print', $data, FALSE);


}
```

My view page code:

```
<?php foreach ($PName as $row): ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['Date']));?></td>


                                    <td>

                                    <?php echo $row['Vno'];?></td>

                                <td><?php echo $row['Parti'];?></td>
                                <td class="price"><?php echo $row['Debit'];?></td>
                                <td class="price1"><?php echo $row['Credit'];?></td>

                            </tr>

                            <?php endforeach ?>
```

How to avoid this problem

Comment: Duplicate voucher number exists but you want to avoid it. Right?

Comment: @DanishAli  date also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Controller Code

```
  $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->distinct(    );
    $this->db->where('Date >=',  $newDate);
    $this->db->where('Date <=',  $newDate2);
    $result = $this->db->get('journal')->result_array(); 


            if($result){
                $finalArray = array();
                $checkArray = array();
                foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                    if(in_array($value['Vno'], $checkArray)){
                        $finalArray[$value['Vno']][] = $value;
                    } else {
                        $checkArray[] = $value['Vno'];
                        $finalArray[$value['Vno']][] = $value;
                    }
                }
                $data['query'] = $finalArray;
```

My Answer Image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8y6f.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, get unique `Date` and `Vno` from DB

```
$this->db->select('Date, Vno');
$this->db->distinct();
$query = $this->db->get('journal')->result();
```

Now, use these to get all the records from DB

```
$unique_date = array(); $unique_vno = array();
foreach($query as $row){
    array_push($unique_vno, $row->Vno);
    array_push($unique_date, $row->Date);  
 }

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where_in('Date',  $unique_date);
$this->db->where_in('Vno',  $unique_vno);
$query = $this->db->get('journal');    
$data['PName']=$query->result_array();
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything sir

Comment: The same result is avaliable

Comment: @Tom I've made some changes in my answer

Comment: Using group_by the another information is not displaying

Comment: @Tom another changes